# How to create a JSON structure for this

Tags: json

Can you tell me how to create a Json objecct for this
I think it is a JSON with children JSON objects.

```
[{
  "data": {
    "ID": "56e819a90111257894be41c9e310f8cb",
    "name": "Email_____2016-03-15 10_18_16",
    "objCode": "DOCU",
    "description": null,
   "lastUpdateDate": "2016-03-15T10:18:17:551-0400"
  }
}: null]
```

I did this

```
JSONObject childVal = new JSONObject();
JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();

try {

    childVal.put("ID", "56e819a90111257894be41c9e310f8cb");
    childVal.put("name", "Email_____2016-03-15 10_18_16");
    childVal.put("objCode", "DOCU");
    childVal.put("description", "null");
    childVal.put("lastUpdateDate", "2016-03-15T10:18:17:551-0400");

    parent.put("data", childVal);
```

but how do i get the parent [   object : null]

thanks

Comment: it's an array of objects of objects. and since you haven't told us what language your'e using, we can't help you.

Comment: map as a key - there is no such a thing in JSON.